# NOT EXIST in a subquery, joined back to separate table

Tags: sql, subquery, informix

Running a report to figure out which parts in our system have not had an order within a certain period of time. Other minor aspects to this report, this is the main area I'm struggling. Best I could figure out is getting a list of parts that HAVE had orders during this time then comparing it back against the other table, but either my joins or subqueries are working correctly.

Does NOT EXIST work like this?

```
SELECT i.customer_no AS CustNumber,
i.part_no AS PartNumber,  
p.cpt_prog_mat
FROM fit_part_info i  
INNER JOIN fit_part_forecast f ON f.part_info_id = i.id
INNER JOIN orrcpt_rec p ON i.part_no = p.cpt_cus_part_no
WHERE (accounting_period = "201911" AND cpt_prog_mat = "Y") OR
(accounting_period = "201912" AND cpt_prog_mat = "Y") OR
(accounting_period = "202001" AND cpt_prog_mat = "Y") OR
(accounting_period = "202002" AND cpt_prog_mat = "Y") AND

NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT(i.part_no)
FROM INNER JOIN ortord_rec o ON i.part_no = o.ord_cus_part_no
WHERE (o.ord_comp_dt < 20191126 AND o.ord_comp_dt > 20190925 AND o.ord_cus_part_no <> ""))

GROUP BY i.part_no, i.customer_no, p.cpt_prog_mat
ORDER BY i.part_no;
```

Comment: You probably want `where cpt_prog_mat = "Y" and accounting_period in ("201911", ...) AND not exists ...`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are missing the initial table name in the subselect.

try

```
NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM fit_part_info i
  INNER JOIN ortord_rec o ON i.part_no = o.ord_cus_part_no
  WHERE
    o.ord_comp_dt < 20191126
    AND o.ord_comp_dt > 20190925
    AND o.ord_cus_part_no <> ""
)
```

btw, you can use `select 1` bc you don't actually need to select something if you are just checking for its existence